# JS Regex: How to capture repeating pattern into different array elements?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I have a target string like:
`str='Every "red","white","blue" flower is $7.'`

If I run `/Every ("(.+)",?)+ flower is \$(.+)/.exec(str)`, I will get `"red","white","blue"` as a whole output element, but what I want is `["red,"white","blue"]`.

Is there a way to do this, or I can only use `split`?

Thanks!

Comment: If the double-quotes are balanced, either lookbehind for `"` in a global `.match` while matching non-`"`s, or repeatedly exec `"([^"]+)"` and extract the first group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`global` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) RegExp and a [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) solution would be the most practical:

```
str.match(/"(.*?)"/g) // [ '"red"', '"white"', '"blue"' ]
```

Comment: Is this able to be modified to also capture other patterns like the tail `$7`?

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai yes doing something like `/("(.*?)")|(\$\d+)/g` would catch that format as well

Comment: Hmm, this is a bit different from what I want to ask, but I think I can use the combination. Thank you.